# llvm-cov: statistics for uninstantiated functions

Tags: code-coverage, llvm-cov

I'm starting to work with `llvm-cov` to produce coverage statistics for my project. `llvm-cov` has several categories: line coverage, function coverage and region coverage. But they all consider only *instantiated functions*, functions which are not instantiated are simply ignored. This way it is easy to get close to 100% coverage for files which have a low percentage of instantiated functions, which is not what I want. Is it possible to make `llvm-cov` consider even uninstantiated functions or make it produce separate coverage statistics?

Comment: Could you give an example of an uninstantiated function that lacks coverage? For C++ code, functions that are specialized but not used should be covered. To my knowledge, functions that are not specialized at all are not handled -- this is probably a bug.

Comment: @vedantk: For example any template function which is not used.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, unfortunately not. This is a missing capability in llvm-cov.

The reason for this is that clang does not emit any code for unspecialized templates, and the coverage generation logic depends on clang emitting code for a function. This is a weird limitation. The compiler does have enough information to describe these templates.

Edit: Of course, another point to consider is that C++ translation units tend to contain absolutely enormous amounts of unspecialized/uninstantiated templates, and if the compiler were to emit coverage mapping regions for each of these, compile-time and binary size would likely regress massively.